# Animate to resize height of UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm facing very weird issue, I have UIView grandWrapper namely in which I'm adding many subviews now when i animate the height of my grandWrapper to zero, ideally height of grandWrapper should be zero and all the inner views should disappear since they were existing inside that grandWrapper View but It animates the height to zero and all the subviews are still there. Can anyone help?

P.s. Im creating subviews programmatically. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make subview's `autoresizingMask` property contains `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` if you want the subviews resize its height according to their parent's height.

Or you can set the view's `clipsToBounds` property to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit confused from your question

1.If you want to remove your grandWrapper sub views then call below function

```
-(void)clearReportContent
{
    if(grandWrapper!=nil)
        [[grandWrapper subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
```

2.If sub views are appearing on screen when you do the grandWrapper height to zero,
then set `grandWrapper.cliptoBounds=YES;` at start where you add the sub view on grandWrapper.

Comment: Im not removing it, I'm animating the height of grandWrapper from 0 to 150 then again on button tap 150-0 so i want all the inner views to disappear with respect to their parent disappearance.

Comment: Then use second option or set the auto resizing mask for subviews as said by @KudoCC